# Uncaught TypeError: areFieldsSet is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined-function

I have my JS code as :

```
    $(function () { //line-1
     if(window.location.search.length >1){
    //doSomething ;
     areFieldsSet(); //call this function
    } //end of if 

    var areFieldsSet = function(){
    //do something
    }
    //do many things
   } // end of line-1 function
```

Now, I am getting an error when I am trying to refer areFieldsSet function as described in the question title. 
Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: what is the error you have ? and why aren't you simply try to do : `function areFieldsSet() { ... }` ?

Comment: @Alex Uncaught TypeError: areFieldsSet is not a function

Comment: @Alex I cant use function areFieldsSet() { ... } because this function is being referenced from many areas in the code and I just cannot declare this in an if condition.

Comment: @nerd.post: I don't understand your comment. Isn't it exactly the other way round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining the function after calling it.

JavaScript does something called "hoisting". Take a look at this article: [Variable and Function Hoisting in JavaScript](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting)

The rules can sometimes be confusing, but basically function definitions using the `function x()` notation are implicitly moved to the top, and variable *definitions* are moved as well, but not their initialization!

For example, `var x = 5;` somewhere further down will work as if `var x;` was written at the start of your code block/function, but `x = 5;` further down. So `x` will be defined before the assignment, but with a value of `undefined`.

So, you have two options: Either you move your `areFieldsSet` function above the place where you call it, or you change it from `var areFieldsSet = function()` to just `function areFieldsSet()` which will make it eligible to function hoisting (and not just variable hoisting).

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript code works in 2 phases.

First Phase - It declares all variable's with `var` keyword (only declares, not initialize) and all function declarations ( function F() {} ).

Second Phase - It starts to run.

In your code you have your **function expression**, not a declaration, so when you are trying to call that function in line

```
  $(function () { //line-1
     if(window.location.search.length >1){
    //doSomething ;
     areFieldsSet(); //call this function
    } //end of if 

    var areFieldsSet = function(){
    //do something
    }
    //do many things
   }
```

The JavaScript engine knows that there is a variable with name **areFieldsSet**(because it is declared in the First Phase), but assinging to it a function will work only when your code will achieve to the

```
var areFieldsSet = function(){
        //do something
        }
```

So when you are trying to call it like a function, you get error because JavaScript doesn't know that it is an function.